# textfield disappearing when keyboard present for scrollview

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextfield

i have a problem with keyboard appearing in UiscrollView.

i added a UIScrollview as

```
scrlView=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 140, 1000, 600)];
scrlView.scrollEnabled=YES;
scrlView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=YES;
scrlView.bounces=NO;
```

to this scrollView i have added 10 rows of UITextFields each row has 5 textFields each textfield height is 50px.
When ever trying to edit textfield it is overlapping by keyBoard.For that i tried this code

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];


   - (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
  {
NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
CGRect bkgndRect = selectetTxtfld.superview.frame;
bkgndRect.size.height += kbSize.height;
[selectetTxtfld.superview setFrame:bkgndRect];
[scrlView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, selectetTxtfld.frame.origin.y) animated:YES];
}
```

}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent

```
 - (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
  {
  UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;

  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
     scrlView.contentInset = contentInsets;
  }];
  scrlView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
 }
```

But the textField not appearing on the keyboard.it appearing at the scrollview ypoint position

help me on this problem.I saw many answers in StackOverFlow.But not cleared my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification {

NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
CGFloat offSetAfterKeyboardIsDisplayed = scrlview.contentOffset.y + kbSize.height;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
//adding content inset at the bottom of the scrollview
   scrlView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetMake(0,0,kbSize.height,0);
   [scrlview setContentOffset:offSetAfterKeyboardIsDisplayed]
}];
}


- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{

NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
CGFloat offSetAfterKeyboardResigns = scrlview.contentOffset.y - kbSize.height;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
   scrlView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
   [scrlview setContentOffset:offSetAfterKeyboardResigns]
}];
}
```

Comment: Showing Error at scrlView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetMake(0,0,kbSize.height,0); Assigning to 'UIEdgeInsets' (aka 'struct UIEdgeInsets') from incompatible type 'int'

Comment: Showing error at                                              [scrlView setContentOffset:offSetAfterKeyboardIsDisplayed]                 Sending 'const CGFloat' (aka 'const float') to parameter of incompatible type 'CGPoint' (aka 'struct CGPoint')

Comment: tnks for answering again.It is very important for me now

Comment: oh.. i am so sorry.. i dont have xcode now.. instead of setContentOffset:offSetAfterKeyboardIsDisplayed you need to write setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrlView.contentOffset.x, offSetAfterKeyboardIsDisplayed). please make the same changes for setContentOffset:offSetAfterKeyboardResigns.. sorry for the mistake.. reason for this error(for your knowledge) is the offSetAfterKeyboardIsDisplayed is of type CGFloat but ContentSize is of type CGPoint(which is a struct)..

Comment: and its UIEdgeInsetsMake not UIEdgeInsetMake.. :) my bad

Comment: Thanks, But the textField appearing out off scrollview bounds for some textFields.My scroll view has 15 rows of textFields.if last row textfield is selected it showing out of bounds in scrollview

Comment: Thanks for your supporting..And that again the textfield is at scrollView Yposition(0) only.Not at top of keyBoard

Answer (score 1):

in keyboardWasShown: 
1.add content inset at bottom of the scrollview with value equal to the height of the keyboard.
2. setContentOffset = current offset+ height of the keyboard.
Note: 1&3 should be done in an animation block with duration equalto 0.30

in keyboardWillBeHidden:
1.set contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
2. setContentOffset = current offset - height of the keyboard.
Note: 1&3 should be done in an animation block with duration equalto 0.30

This should solve ur problem :)

Comment: Thanks for answer .Pls can you brief it with some sample code.I am new to xcode deve